# How do I display a line in a Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, line

I would like to draw a line between 2 images in Java swing.

I have found different ways of drawing lines but none the way that I want to which makes me think maybe I just need to insert an image of a line where I want it?

in any case I want something along the lines of

```
O---O---O---O
```

To be displayed where the 'O's are images and the dashes are where I want lines...

I hope this is clear and I'm not being an idiot :P

Thanks a lot,

Alexander

Comment: You could just just draw a line, then draw the images over the line at set increment points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, you could just just draw a line, then draw the images over the line at set increment points

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final Image image = new ImageIcon(Test.class
                        .getResource("/resources/images/stackoverflow.png"))
                        .getImage();
                final BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(5f);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);
                        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                        g2.setStroke(stroke);
                        g2.drawLine(10, 75, 290, 75);
                        for (int x = 10; x < 300; x += 50) {
                            g2.drawImage(image, x, 59, this);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(300, 150);
                    }
                };

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Line With Images",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, wasn't sure if you could/how I would do that :)

Answer (score 0):

just invoke the method [drawLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and insert the parameters for the position :)